# jQuery append() issue in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I have the following script which I am running.  It loops through each table in the page and appends "*Table n [Table Title]*" below each table.

This script works fine in Chrome, Mozilla but not IE 6 or 7.  No errors are captured.  Can anyone help with explaining if I have missed something here in my script or is this a bug in jQuery?  If this is a jQuery issue, can anyone suggest a workaround?

```
        $('table').each(function(index,value){
        var obj = $(this).attr('title');
        var i = index;
        var txt = '<span class="toc-caption">Table '+(i+1)+' '+obj+'</span>';
        $(this).append(txt);
    });
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your appending a span to a table which of course is not correct and quite rightly ie is blowing up.

Try [.after](http://api.jquery.com/after/) or you could use the [caption](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/table.caption) tag of the table

```
 $('table').each(function(index,value){
    var obj = $(this).attr('title');
    var i = index;
    var txt = '<span class="toc-caption">Table '+(i+1)+' '+obj+'</span>';
    $(this).after(txt);
```